# How do I combine these two queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 queries from MS Access:
Query 1:

```
Select Date, Username
From Table1
where Date>='9/1/2013'
group by Date, Username
```

After run the Query 1, I got the unique users list and run Query 2 to get the total counts:

```
Select Query1.Date, Count(Query1.Date)
from Query1
Where Date>='9/1/2013'
```

How do I translate this into SQL studio script to get unique users then count the total numbers from Date? Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Do you want a count for each users? So, User -- Date -- Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Select q.Date, Count(q.Date)
FROM (
    Select Date, Username
    From Table1
    where Date>='9/1/2013'
    group by Date, Username
) q
GROUP BY q.Date
```

Comment: @user2912479 Be sure to up-vote him too so he can get all of his glorious points. =)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a sub query, try this:

```
SELECT Date, Count (date)
FROM Database.User.Table1 
Where Date > '9/1/2013' 
Group By date, username
```

Per the comments:

```
SELECT Date, username, Count (date)
FROM Database.User.Table1 
Where Date >= '9/1/2013' 
Group By date, username
```

Comment: He wanted a date >= 9/1/2013

Comment: Also, doesn't username have to be in the select to group by it?

Comment: @yatrix, you are correct. I've updated to reflect that. Since the OP has the "From" query grouped by username, I kept username inside.

Comment: I like your second query, but i'm not sure he wants username in the final query. As for your first query, it will return wrong results, as it will give equal dates multiple times if usernames have records with same dates

Comment: I agree with @FilipeSilva. It seems like he has no actual purpose for username since the second query is his desired result. That's why I left it out of my answer. =)

Comment: Sorry. Even the second query will return multiple results for the same date, and i don't think that's what he wanted. Hence the subquery.

Comment: @FilipeSilva it was something I couldn't have guessed. Either of our answers could have been correct but he didn't give much information about his requirements. Either way +1